# How to rotate category title with facet_wrap?

Tags: r, ggplot2, facet-wrap

look at my code:

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(mpg, aes(displ, hwy)) +
  geom_point() +
  facet_wrap(vars(class))
```

[image]

How to rotate the title of each category (2seater, compact etc), to place them on the right and horizontal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could place the strip text on the right via the `strip.position` argument of `facet_wrap` and make them horizontal via the `theme` option `strip.text.y`:

```r
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(mpg, aes(displ, hwy)) +
  geom_point() +
  facet_wrap(vars(class), strip.position = "right") +
  theme(strip.text.y = element_text(angle = 0))
```

[image]